# What does "Who's for another round of toast" mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard it at a meal in a movie but I couldn't understand it. Can somebody tell me what it means, please?

Comment: Were they eating toast as part of the meal?

Comment: Yes, they were eating toast.

Comment: Ugh. I cannot believe  you would leave such pertinent information out of  your question.

Comment: See [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/round) **noun** definition 6 (bread-specific) and, more generally, **noun** definition 4.1 (the definition cites drinks, but application is wider). The noun definitions are found under the adjective definitions. These definitions should be added to your question as part of what Stack Exchange calls "research". You can then ask about any aspect of the definitions etc that are still unclear to you.

Comment: Do you not understand "Who's for"?

Comment: Maybe there's some confusion between *burnt bread* and *drink to honor a person*.  This always seems an odd vocabulary homograph to me, but apparently it has quite an entertaining origin.

Comment: There's even a specific Longman's Dictionary definition for [*a round of toast.*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/round-of-toast)

Comment: @Fumble - I can’t even tell for sure if this should be parsed as [Who’s for another] [round of toast], or [Who’s for another round] [of toast]? This could have been an excellent question with a few added details.

Comment: @J.R.: In the right context you could omit the last 2, the last three, or even the last *four* words *(**another round of toast**)*. That last one needs a bit more contrived context, as in *John thinks we should all have another round of toast each, but I'm against it. Who's for?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, the only thing _truly_ puzzling me is why more information wasn’t included in the question.

Comment: @J.R.: I didn't bother to mention the idiomatic usage *[another] **round** of X* precisely because the specific case *a round of **toast*** actually gets its own dictionary entry. Well, to be *precise*, I didn't actually know that for sure when I ignored it while posting my answer, but I assumed it would be sufficiently easy to look up that OP wasn't likely to be asking about that aspect of the cited text. And the reality is that ***to be for X = to want [to be given] X*** isn't a particularly common usage, so I took it for granted that was the source of confusion for OP here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question **Who's for ...?** means "Who is in favor of ...?", that is, in context, "Who would like to have ...?".

To be **for** something in this usage means to be **pro** not **anti**.

> Are you **for** the new changes to the privacy policy, where they're allowed to have their device listen to your conversations and send you ads about things you've talked about?

A **round** is an iteration of something. In a meal context, a serving or helping.

A **round** can also be a slice of something, such as a slice of bread.

Answer (score 3):

I'd normally expect *Who **wants** another [round of toast, beer, etc.]?* In such constructions, ***for*** approximately corresponds to ***is in favour of*** (or ***wants*** which might not *always* mean exactly the same thing).

There's also *Who's **up for** another beer?*, but to me that rather suggests a "straw poll" context. Perhaps the bar they're currently in is about to close, and the speaker is calling for a "collective decision" because they'd need to relocate to an all-night bar if they want to continue drinking.

---

Which isn't to say that OP's cited version is "incorrect", it's just less common. And whereas *to be **up for** [something]* is very much an *informal* usage, to me the plain form *to be **for** [something]* has significant *formal* connotations (in a debate, say, *We are for the motion, and they are against it.)*

Comment: **Who's for** is not really uncommon. https://community.three.ie/t5/The-Living-Room/who-s-for-pancakes/td-p/44727

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I said it's ***less*** common. Which it obviously is - I found nearly 1000 written instances of [*Who wants a beer?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Who+wants+a+beer%22), compared to just 91 for [*Who's for a beer?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Who%27s+for+a+beer%22). And none at all for the ridiculously stilted [*Who **is** for a beer?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Who+is+for+a+beer%22)